# Chartjs - destroy() does nothing

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I've got a problem with chartJS. I'm calling a function to create a new chart. The creation works, but I would like to destroy any previous charts, so that I get a new one when calling a function.

This is my code at the moment:

```
var chartID;

function addData(chartType,data) {

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        dataLabels.push(data[i][0]);
        dataPoints.push(data[i][1]);
        //console.log(data[i][1]);
    }

    if(chartID){
        console.log('destroy');
        chartID.destroy();
    }

    var ctx = document.getElementById('chart01').getContext('2d');


    chartID = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: chartType,
        data: {
            labels: dataLabels,
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Labels',
                data: dataPoints,
                backgroundColor: '#333'
            }]
        },
        options: {
            maintainAspectRatio: false,
            aspectRatio: 1
        }
    });         
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a runnable example so that we can check why ```chartID.destroy()``` has no effect? I tried ```destroy()``` with the samples online available at https://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/charts/bar/vertical.html and that worked flawlessly. But they use window.yourChartName to define a chart.

Answer (score 3):

Even I had the same issue earlier. I simply added a condition to check the chart variable is empty or not.

```
if(chartID != null){
   chartID.destroy();
}
```

Include this at the top of the function. It'll work fine as you are declaring `chartID` globally. This way you don't need to redeclare the chart again.

Comment: As you can see in the code I posted, I already got a condition set. Which only fires when there is an chart. But it doesnt work. The same chart is created over and over again when I execute the funtion.

Comment: In the condition, you are checking whether the `chartID` is true or not. So remove that condition and try to implement one above. Here you can check `chartID` is `null` or not.. If it's null there is no effect. If it's not null call the `chartID.destroy()` method. So always it'll check the chart's existence.

Comment: The condition isn't problem. Because it is calling the destroy() the way I set the condition. Problem is that the destroy() isnt doing anything. The chart is getting created over and over again.

Comment: In the condition we are checking the chart is null or not. If it's not null then it must be a chart. We can call the `destroy` method only on the chart instance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const chartCanvas = document.getElementById('myChart');

            if( window.lineChart != undefined){
                window.lineChart.destroy();
            }
            window.lineChart = new Chart(chartCanvas,{
                type: 'line',
                data: {
                    labels: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
                    datasets: [
                        {
                            label: 'Cases',
                            data: [23,42,22,45,56,77,33,22,46,77,32,44],
                            fill: false,
                          //  backgroundColor: 'red',
                            borderColor: ['rgb(255, 255, 0)'],
                            lineTension: 0.2,
                            borderWidth: 1.5
                        }
                    ]
                },
                options:{
                    title: {
                        display: true,
                        text: "Temperature variation",
                        fontFamily: 'Arial',
                        fontSize: 16
                    },
                    legend: {
                        display: true,
                        position: "right",
                        labels: {
                            boxWidth:10
                        }
                    },
                    //stacked - start with 0 as minimum value for y-axis
                    scales:{
                        yAxes: [{
                            stacked: true,
                            gridLines:{
                                display: true,
                                color: '#FFFFFF',
                                lineWidth: 1,
                                zeroLineColor: 'blue',
                                zeroLineWidth: 2,
                                drawBorder: false // this to remove the ghost line that appears
                                                  // when you add zeroLine x-axis
                            }

                        }],
                        xAxes: [{             
                           gridLines:{
                                display: true,
                                zeroLineColor: 'blue',
                                zeroLineWidth: 1,
                                color: 'transparent'
                            }
                        }]
                    }

                }
            });
```

----------------- Added code sample above ------------------

I had some issues with ChartJs. Somehow, it created a new chart with the previous chart still in the canvas which shows up when you hover.

This worked for me:

```
if( window.chartID!= undefined){
                window.chartID.destroy();
            }

chartID = new Chart(ctx, {...});
```

Comment: window. doesnt work for me. Getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'destroy' of undefined.

Comment: That's because you've not initialized it. put (window.chartID = ""; in the beginning of your code where you have var chartID).

Comment: when I set window.chartID I just get syntax error unexpected token '.'

Answer (score 0):

I am creating multiple charts on click.
but before creating chart I just destroy any previous charts
so , thats how it looks

```
    var chartStatus
    // on one onclick
    if (chartStatus) {    chartStatus.destroy();  }
    chartStatus = new Chart(document.getElementById("co2Chart"), co2Config);
    // on another onclick    
    if (chartStatus) {    chartStatus.destroy();  }
    chartStatus = new Chart(document.getElementById("tempChart"), tempConfig);
```